# Uniform distribution on unit circle

Tags: random, distributions, regions

I need a uniform distribution on the unit circle

```
(x; y) : x^2 + y^2 <= 1
```

with the density

```
f(x) = (2/Pi) Sqrt[1-x^2]
```

as a marginal distribution of pairs considered in point `e`.

I have no idea how to implement this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please try to get a basic knowledge of the Mathematica syntax before asking

Answer (score 6):

For a uniform distribution on the unit circle you want the angle to be uniform on {0, 2Pi}

```
thetaDist = UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}];

xDist = TransformedDistribution[
   Cos[theta], theta \[Distributed] thetaDist];

Assuming[-1 < x < 1, PDF[xDist, x] // Simplify]
```

> 1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - x^2])

Verifying that this is properly scaled

```
Integrate[PDF[xDist, x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> 1

```
ListPlot[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@
  RandomVariate[thetaDist, 200],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListPlot[
 Flatten[
  {{#, Sqrt[1 - #^2]}, {#, -Sqrt[1 - #^2]}} & /@
   RandomVariate[xDist, 200],
  1],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: @wolfies - the points **on** (as opposed to **within**) the unit circle are the points `{Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}` with `theta` uniformly distributed on `{0, 2Pi}`. The distribution of `x` is `TransformedDistribution[
   Cos[theta], theta \[Distributed] thetaDist]` For a given `x`, the corresponding `y`s on the unit circle are just `Sqrt[1-x^2]` and `-Sqrt[1-x^2]`.  Hence the mapping of `{{#, Sqrt[1 - #^2]}, {#, -Sqrt[1 - #^2]}}` onto the list of random `x` values.

Answer (score 3):

Since V10.2, there is [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html):

```
pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 2000];
Graphics[{
  Circle[],
  Red, Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(If the unit circle was desired, use `Circle[]` in place of `Disk[]`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide other insights. `RandomPoint` as per MichaelE2 versus user defined probability distribution and confirmation desired marginal distribution:

```
pd = ProbabilityDistribution[
  Piecewise[{{1/Pi, 0 < x^2 + y^2 <= 1}}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
md = MarginalDistribution[pd, 1]
PDF[md, x]
Show[Histogram3D[pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 100000], Automatic, "PDF"],
  Plot3D[PDF[pd, {x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None]]
Show[Histogram[pts[[All, 1]], Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[PDF[md, x], {x, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, `WignerSemicircleDistribution[]` is built-in.

Comment: @J.M. yes thank you. I just wanted to illustrate `MarginalDistribution` for user-defined probability distribution. Your comment is instructive (as usual). :) Best wishes for the festive season.