# Sampling a phase space uniformly for a given energy?

Tags: random, distributions, physics

The energy for a 1D harmonic oscillator can be written:
$$
E = \frac{1}{2 m} p^2 + \frac{m \omega^2}{2} x^2
$$
where x is position and p is the momentum.

I would like to sample phase space $(x,p)$ **uniformly** (generating random numbers), in the case where:
$$
\frac{1}{2 m} = \frac{m \omega^2}{2},
$$
trajectories with the same energy $E'$ in phase space lie in a circle centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{2 m E'}$. Therefore, we can use the trick in this answer: [uniform distribution on unit circle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63805/uniform-distribution-on-unit-circle)

In my particular problem, the energy is given by:
$$
E = \frac{p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2}{2 m} + V(x,y,z)
$$
where $V(x,y,z)$ is the potential energy of Cartesian co-ordinates. I would like to generate random numbers $(x,y,z,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ that are uniformly distributed in allowed phase space all with energy $E'$

Comment: ...This sounds like a hard research problem. Even in your 1D example, if you don't have $\frac1{2m}=\frac{m\omega^2}2$ you're trying to sample uniformly from the boundary of an *ellipse*, and that's not easy.

Comment: Do you have a particular function in mind for `V(x,y,z)`?  If not, can you state whether `E = E'` is a continuously differentiable closed surface?

Comment: The potential I have in mind is $V(x,y,z) = c \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4 a^2} + \frac{z^2}{a^2}}$ where $a$ and $c$ are constants. When I want to generate the random numbers, $a, c, m$ and $E$ will be some numerical value.

Comment: @user29165, do you really mean to include the `Sqrt`, which causes `V` not to be analytical at the origin?  I would have expected something like `V [x, y, z] = c ((x^2 + y^2)/(4 a^2) + z^2/a^2)`, analogous to your 1D example.

Comment: In my case, I do have the sqrt in the potential, I was just listing the 1d harmonic oscillator as an example as it would be familiar to most people.

Answer (score 7):

Solving the one-dimensional problem is a first step toward solving the three-dimensional problem described in the question and comments.  Without loss of generality, it can be written after renormalization as

```
1 == p^2 + Sqrt[x^2/4]
```

Noting that phase space is mirror-symmetric about both axes, we solve for the phase curve in the quadrant `p > 0`, `x > 0`.

```
xphase = x /. Assuming[x > 0, Solve[%, x]][[1, 1]];
Plot[xphase, {p, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {p, x}]
```

[image: phase space]

To "sample phase space uniformly", we compute the arc length of this curve and sample it uniformly.

```
dsdp = Sqrt[1 + (D[xphase, p])^2];
arc = Simplify[s[p] /. DSolve[{s'[p] == dsdp, s[0] == 0}, s[p], p][[1]]]
```

with solution

```
(4*p*Sqrt[1 + 16*p^2] + ArcSinh[4*p])/8
```

Knowing `arc` as a function of `p`, we compute the inverse function in the usual manner.

```
pinv[s_] := p /. FindRoot[arc - s, {p, .5}]
```

Finally, following [63805](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63805/uniform-distribution-on-unit-circle), we obtain

```
ListPlot[{pinv[#], xphase /. p -> pinv[#]} & /@ 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, arc /. p -> 1}], 100], AxesLabel -> {p, x}]
```

[image: distribution]

Presumably, the complete problem can be solved by generating a uniform distribution on the unit sphere in six dimensions and mapping it to the surface generated by the Hamiltonian described in the question and comments.

Answer (score 5):

**Alternative 2D Solution**

A simpler and more readily generalizable alternative to the solution presented in my previous Answer can be obtained by noting that a `UniformDistribution` on the curve shown in the first figure is equivalent to a `ProbabilityDistribution` in `p` weighted by `dsdp`,

```
ProbabilityDistribution[dsdp/arcmax, {p, 0, 1}]
```

as can be can be demonstrated by

```
ListPlot[{#, 2 (1 - #^2)} & /@ RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[dsdp/arcmax, {p, 0, 1}], 100],
  AxesLabel -> {p, x}]
```

which reproduces the second plot in the earlier Answer.

**6D Solution (Almost)**

Without loss of generality, the full problem can be written after renormalization as

```
1 == px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + Sqrt[x^2/4 + y^2/4 + z^2]
```

Subsequent calculations can be simplified considerably by transforming momentum space to spherical coordinates and configuration space to cylindrical coordinates.

```
1 == p^2 + Sqrt[z^2 + r^2/4]
```

where `p^2 = px^2 + py^2 + pz^2` and `r^2 = x^2 + y^2`.  Noting that phase space is mirror-symmetric about all axes, we solve for the surface represented by this equation for `{z > 0, r > 0}`.

```
surface = z /. Assuming[{z > 0, r > 0}, Solve[%, z]][[2]];
Plot3D[surface, {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {p, r, s}]
(* Sqrt[4 - 8*p^2 + 4*p^4 - r^2]/2 *)
```

[image: Phase surface]

The differential area of this surface is given by

```
darea = Sqrt[1 + D[surface, p]^2 + D[surface, r]^2] // Simplify;
```

and the total area by

```
area = Integrate[p^2 r darea, {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 2 (1 - p^2)}] // N
```

(Its value is 0.401377.)  The resulting probability function is simply

```
Piecewise[{{p^2 r darea/area, 0 <= r <= 2 (1 - p^2)}}, 0]
```

Finally, we transform back to the original coordinates to obtain

```
{px, py, pz, x, y, z} = 
  {p Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], p Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], p Cos[θ], r Cos[ξ], r Sin[ξ], 
   p Cos[θ], r Cos[ξ], r Sin[ξ], Sqrt[4 - 8*p^2 + 4*p^4 - r^2]/2}
```

Here, `θ` is drawn from

```
RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[Sin[θ0], {θ0, 0, Pi/2}]]
```

`ϕ` and `ξ` are drawn from

```
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, Pi/2}]]
```

and we would like to draw `{p, r}` from

```
RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[
  Piecewise[{{p^2 r darea/area, 0 <= r <= 2 (1 - p^2)}}, 0], {p, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 2}]]
```

Unfortunately, `ProbabilityDistribution` cannot handle this expression, as noted in [69150](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69150/help-with-multivariate-probabilitydistribution).  Presumably, one of the approaches given in [2635](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/randomvariate-from-2-dimensional-probability-distribution) can.